# Javascript : 'Variable Not Defined' inside a self invoking function

Tags: javascript, scope

I wrote the following code that outputs the sum of squared iterating numbers:

```
(function () {
    var i = 4, sum = 0; 
    while(i--) sum+=i*i;
})();
console.log(sum);
```

The problem is I get the following error in console: sum is undefined unless I take the sum out and declare it as global scope:
//this works but this is not what I want.

```
sum = 0;    
(function ( ) {
    var i=4 
    while(i--) sum+=i*i;
})();
console.log(sum);
```

Could some one help me understand?
Thanks

Comment: It's an issue of scope. You can't use the `sum` variable outside of the scope in which it was declared. If you're going to log `sum` in the global scope, then you must declare it globally. I see nothing wrong with using the code as it exists above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are accessing `sum` outside your function scope at the line:
`console.log(sum)`, where sum is not visible.

If you do not want to put `sum` in global scope, then you got to take the statement `console.log(sum)` within the function scope.

Answer (score 5):

```
var sum = (function ( ) {
  var i=4, sum = 0; 
  while(i--) sum+=i*i;
  return sum;
})();
console.log(sum);
```

You created a local variable called `sum` and want to use it outside it's scope. You don't want to declare it in a higher scope so you have to *export* it.

The only way to export local (primitive) variables is the `return` statement.

Answer (score 3):

A self-invoking function has its own scope  (i.e. place to live for variables), so `sum` ceases to exist after the function and all dependent closures finished executing and it is not accessible from outside. In fact, having a separate scope that won't spoil the global or any other scope is the main reason why People use self executing functions.

Answer (score 0):

you are defining `sum` inside the function which is local variable. and printing the sum outside the function which is out of scope.